# Modifying list contents in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like:

```
list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to append a number at the start of every value in the list programmatically, say the number is 9. I want the new list to be like:

```
list = [[9,1,2,3],[9,4,5,6],[9,7,8,9]]
```

How do I go about doing this in Python? I know it is a very trivial question but I couldn't find a way to get this done.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
for sublist in thelist:
  sublist.insert(0, 9)
```

**don't** use built-in names such as `list` for your own stuff, that's just a stupid accident in the making -- call YOUR stuff `mylist` or `thelist` or the like, **not** `list`.

**Edit**: as the OP aks how to insert > 1 item at the start of each sublist, let me point out that the most efficient way is by assignment of the multiple items to a slice of each sublist (most list mutators can be seen as readable alternatives to slice assignments;-), i.e.:

```
for sublist in thelist:
  sublist[0:0] = 8, 9
```

`sublist[0:0]` is the empty slice at the start of `sublist`, and by assigning items to it you're inserting the items at that very spot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... Just an addendum to the question. What if I want to insert two numbers instead of one. like I want to insert 9,8 at the start of every item in the list?

Comment: @Aamir: call insert() multiple times, or less efficiently, concatenate the lists: `[9,8] + sublist`.

Comment: @Amir: or, most efficiently, assign to the empty slice at the start -- let me edit the answer to show that.

Comment: After benchmarking with timeit, the [0:0] method is almost 2x faster than the insert() one. Mostly because it avoids a function call I guess. Anyway, it's less readable.

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> someList = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> someList = [[9] + i for i in someList]
>>> someList
[[9, 1, 2, 3], [9, 4, 5, 6], [9, 7, 8, 9]]
```

(someList because list is already used by python)

Comment: Woot! TMTOWTDI in Python!! :)

Comment: We don't get out of our way to forbid alternatives!-)  OTOH, my insert-based solution is better performing and general, so it WILL be "the" obvious way to do it for programmers advanced enough to microbenchmark things (e.g. with python -mtimeit) OR to be familiar with the internals;-).

Comment: Well, I expect insert() to be faster unless you actually want to create a copy

Answer (score 2):

Use the insert method, which **modifies the list in place**:

```
>>> numberlists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> for numberlist in numberlists:
...  numberlist.insert(0,9)
...
>>> numberlists
[[9, 1, 2, 3], [9, 4, 5, 6]]
```

or, more succintly

```
[numberlist.insert(0,9) for numberlist in numberlists]
```

or, differently, using list concatenation, which **creates a new list**

```
newnumberlists = [[9] + numberlist for numberlist in numberlists]
```

Comment: That list comprehension you're suggesting as "succint" builds and ignores a list of `None`s - yech!-)

Comment: I'm aware of that fact. I just didn't mention it :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing a lot of prepending, 
perhaps consider using [deques](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#deque-objects)* instead of lists:

```
>>> mylist = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

>>> from collections import deque
>>> mydeque = deque()
>>> for li in mylist:
...   mydeque.append(deque(li))
...
>>> mydeque
deque([deque([1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 6]), deque([7, 8, 9])])
>>> for di in mydeque:
...   di.appendleft(9)
...
>>> mydeque
deque([deque([9, 1, 2, 3]), deque([9, 4, 5, 6]), deque([9, 7, 8, 9])])
```

*Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced "deck" and is short for "double-ended queue").  Deques support thread-safe, memory-efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction.

And, as others have mercifully mentioned:  
For the love of all things dull and ugly, 
**please do not** name variables after your favorite data-structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def addNine(val):
    val.insert(0,9)
    return val

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    print map(addNine,s)
```

Output:

```
[[9, 1, 2, 3], [9, 4, 5, 6], [9, 7, 8, 9]]
```